# Metasploitable questions? (2 questions)

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

1. Is it normal that I chose "Metasploitable.vmdk" as the Hard Disk, or was it supposed to be my Hard Disk of Kali Linux?
2. Will I still be able to use Metasploitable with my Kali Linux, even though it's a completely different machine? Or is it supposed to stay like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Metasploitable and Kali Linux are completely unrelated. To clarify this:

> Metasploitable is an intentionally vulnerable Linux virtual machine. This VM can be used to conduct security training, test security tools, and practice common penetration testing techniques. ([Source](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/requirements/))

and

> Kali Linux is an advanced Penetration Testing and Security Auditing Linux distribution [...]. Kali comes with metasploit already available along with numerous other security tools that you can try out against your victim machine. ([Source](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/requirements/))

1. Yes, `Metasploitable.vmdk` is supposed to be the virtual disk for the Metasploitable machine.
2. Yes, you have to install both Metasploitable and Kali Linux into different virtual machines. You can then use Kali Linux for "attacking" Metasploitable via a network emulated by your Hypervisor (VMWare Player, VirtualBox, etc.).

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for clearing that up! And, what's the best Network to use? The NAT one? And thanks again!

Comment: For your purpose either NAT or Host-only mode are preferable.